# Need to get a byte value to a string but it wont let me

Tags: python

I have a byte string beginning with:

```
b"\xa5\x...........
```

I need to convert it to a string value so i can make it json to upload to an api

However when using str() method it returns:

```
'b"\xa5"'
```

When i try to decode() it it returns with an error saying that it cannot deocode byte: "\xa5"

How can i decode it?

Comment: What format are you trying to decode it to?

Comment: utf-8, i also tried ascii not working either

Comment: Well what encoding was used to create it?

Comment: using the default format the open() function uses which im assuming is utf-8

Comment: but the data was written to the file in bytes too, and is an encrypted bytes string, using utf-8 again

Comment: So you're trying to decode this exact string? `'b"\xa5"'`

Comment: No its about 821 bytes but 'b"\xa5"' is the byte that python is refusing to decode

Comment: Try `'b"\xa5"'.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")`

Comment: no error, 0xa5 decodes to utf-8 "¥"

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: no the thing is when i do `b'\xa5`.decode() it returns the error again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206102/discussion-between-linny-and-jojothecodedude).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the encoding you are looking for is `latin1`. `\xa5` in latin1 is `¥`. Try

```
string = b'\xa5'
string.decode('latin1')
```